# Xlib Python Event Handling

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня задача отлавливать смену раскладки. В итоге что я имею, настроил как было написано в официальной документации xlib-python, но код то не работает.

```
from Xlib import display
from Xlib import X
disp = display.Display()
root = disp.screen().root
root.change_attributes(event_mask=display.X.KeymapStateMask)
a = disp.next_event()
print(a)
```

Он не может достигнуть до print(), в чем проблема? Объясните пожалуйста

Comment: Функция `disp.next_event()` ждет событие нажатия на комбинацию клавиш смены клавиатуры

Comment: Так я этого и хочу. Но просто это событие не выкидывается, хочу узнать из за чего это влияет? Также пробовал KeyPress, KeyRelease та же самая проблема.

Comment: Я думаю что в Xorg чтото блокирует в виде разрешений, так что мне бы хотелось про это узнать побольше